# How to get package name from pip when installing zip file?

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

When I run `pip install http://some.domain/path/to/lib.zip` I have no idea what is the name of library I am actually going to install.

How can I, at runtime, figure out the name of the package I am installing?

It should equal the name in setup.py.

Comment: What do you mean when you say `at runtime` in this context?

Comment: @cel this means my code reads a url pointing to zip file and I want to be able to get the package name. command line solutions will be accepted, however solutions that do not involve command lines are preferred.

Comment: Hmh, well you can download the package, unzip to tmp, then read the `setup.py` should be pretty straight forward using just the standard library. Are you looking for a better way? I don't think there is for arbitrary zip files.

Comment: @cel - what do you mean `read` the setup.py. can you write it in code?

Comment: What I mean is: In almost all cases the information is coded into the `setup.py` file. So you have multiple options: Here are a few ideas I have: Try to get the name with a regex. Ugly, but short and will probably work in most of the cases. b) patch the `setup.py` file and run it in you python code. You could e.g. try to replace the `setup` function by a function that records the keyword argument. While this should be easy to implement, this approach has severe security issues. c) use `ast` to fully parse the `setup.py` and extract all information.

Comment: Using `ast` should probably work, but it will be quite complicated I guess. I cannot give you full working code here, just thoughts. I think the main problem is, that `setup.py` files are executed during installation. In the worst case extracting relevant information requires rerunning them, which you usually try to avoid, especially when using a `zip` files from an arbitrary homepage.